# Не способный: на или к?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Человек, не способный на что-то или к чему-то? Как правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да по-всякому можно. Даже без предлога с инфинитивом.
Правда похоже, что это немного разные вещи.
Уберите "не" - все ясно станет.
Способный к наукам - свойство ума, способный на поступок - свойство характера, способный размножаться - биологическое свойство - ну и т.д. С "не" (которое раздельно) - все то же самое.

Вот если "неспособный", то такое впечатление, что и "к чему-то", и "на что-то" - оба не совсем удачны. Только "неспособный мыслить, любить, ждать" - про человеческие качества. Или просто "неспособный", как характеристика, окончательная и бесповоротная. Но это субъективно. Надо бы в нацкорпусе примеров пошукать, может поточнее скажу...

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь Д. Э. "Управление в русском языке": 
***Способный (способен)*** - 1. (имеющий способность, склонность к чему-л.) **К ЧЕМУ**. ***Способный к музыке; Способный к труду; Ее поразило, что Кирилл способен ко лжи и утайкам (Фед.)***. 2. (готовый, расположенный сделать что-то) **НА ЧТО**. ***Способный на жертвы;*** ***Способный на большие дела; Ее пустота не мешала ей бывать способной на порывы чувств по отношению к тому, кто ей нравился (Сим.).***

Неспособный К ЧЕМУ и НА ЧТО. Там же.

Способность К ЧЕМУ и НА ЧТО. Там же.

Comment: Интересно, сам Дитмар Эльяшевич читал эти примеры?
Вы серьёзно полагаете, что "ко лжи и утайкам" - это способность, а не предрасположенность?